# Sinatra app won't run

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I installed Sinatra using RubyGems, created a simple file called hello.rb

file contains:

```
 require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  puts "Hello World"

end
```

I navigated on the terminal to desktop on mac to where i saved the hello.rb and did run the file by: ruby hello.rb  it gives me message it is running with WEBrick on this port 4567
I went to localhost:4567  then i get this message "Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty."

Do i have to save the hello.rb file to the WEBrick server folder to make it work? if so, where is that folder located on the mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return something, as in:

```
get '/' do
  "Hello World" # the return is implicit
end
```

Then it will work. `puts` prints to the command line but returns nil, so nothing was being returned to sinatra.

Comment: Very clever answer thank you, it did work like a charm, can you tell me how can i create a template so i can use html and start building basic ruby using for example reverse methods to do something funny for learning purposes? what next to make my app contains html and css? create a public folder and what else? in what file should i write ruby code? and how to insert it into the html file? I'm a beginner so be patient with me thanks

Comment: Try http://rubysource.com/just-do-it-learn-sinatra-i/ for a tutorial.  But maybe you'd learn more from an example like this:  https://github.com/twilson63/Sinatra-WebSite-Tutorial

Comment: Thank you, the example is so informative, huge difference compared to the complex rails framework. this tiny one is great for me to start coding from scratch. one last question, what kind of libraries Sinatra contains? for example library for authentication?